# hot swap in sbt project without play-plugin

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

When I am using play framework, every time I've changed the code, it will take effect automatically by re-compile the code.

However, when I'm using sbt to run a project without play-plugin, it won't take effect.

I'm wondering if there were a way to make sbt project hot swap the changed code.

My build.sbt is as below:

```
version in ThisBuild := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.6"

lazy val `frontend` = (project in file("frontend")).
  enablePlugins(PlayScala).
  enablePlugins(DockerPlugin).
  settings(
    name := "frontend",
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.frontend
  ).dependsOn(`api`).aggregate(`api`)

lazy val `backend` = (project in file("backend")).
  enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging).
  enablePlugins(DockerPlugin).
  settings(
    name := "backend",
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.backend ++ Seq(cache, ws)
  ).dependsOn(`api`).aggregate(`api`)

lazy val `api` = (project in file("api")).
  settings(
    name := "api",
    libraryDependencies += ws
  )
```

And what I have configured in intellij idea is like below as a sbt task(I can't post images by now):

`"project backend"  ~run`

However, every time I've changed the code in backend, It won't take effect after I've call backend from the frontend.

I'm wondering how I can solve the problem. Thanks for your guys' help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have sbt automatically recompiling any changes by invoking it like this:
    `sbt ~compile`

Comment: Yes, I know this. However, what I want is that my program keep running, i.e., something like `sbt ~run`. But when I do this, the program just keeps in waiting for compiling. It doesn't run.

Comment: So you want each time you change something in the code, to recompile everything and relaunch the entire thing automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ~run, on every change the changeed classes will be compiled and project rerun again. 
If it does not work, you might explain more about your project and structure.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've added my build.sbt to the question. Thanks for you kind reply.

Comment: Is not there any dependency between frontend and backend?
I mean api backend and frontend both are depended on api but there is no dependencies between frontend and backend?
Is it all the sbt file? If yes, so i think you are not using dependency injection.

If you make a dependency from frontend to backend and then run your frontend with ~run should solve your problem.

Comment: This is all the sbt file... And I don't want the frontend to depend on backend so that whatever I have done to backend, frontend needn't to change. And thanks for you patient answer. I see why it doesn't work on my project.

Comment: By the way, I'm using akka actor to connect frontend and backend. So there needn't to be any dependency between front and back.

Answer (score 0):

Open two SBT window.
The one run `~compile`, and another run `~run`.
Hope it will be help.